# What does the notation $\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ mean?

Tags: notation

I am reading a paper on Solomonoff induction:

http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/15137/1/solput.pdf

and it includes notation that I don't understand such as the example in the title of the question and $\lbrace0, 1\rbrace^\omega$. I have looked in some of the references for definitions of this notation but I haven't found them. Is there a book that explains this kind of notation?

Comment: I would interpret $\mathbb N^{>0}$ to refer to an integer $≥1$.  Some authors include $0$ in the natural numbers, and this author wants to exclude that.  As the text says, $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is the standard  [Cantor Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space).  That is, just the usual set of binary sequences.

Comment: I would guess $\Bbb N^{>0}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and that $\{0,1\}^\omega$ is the set of all sequences $\{a_0,a_1,\ldots\}$ with each $a_n\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: My only guess would be it denotes $\mathbb N^{*}$.

Comment: @Bernard $^*$ often denotes the multiplicatively invertible elements. So in my book, $\Bbb N^*=\{1\}$.

Comment: For me, the set of invertible elements for multiplication (when there are two operations) is better denoted $\mathbb N^\times$ (or better, to be a purist, $\mathbf N^\times$).

Comment: @Arthur I agree with the notation of Bernard $\mathbb N^{*}$ (usual notation in Italy, but in the several book of high school the notation is different). In fact if you seen in "Notazione" (notation) https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_naturale you have naturals number without the $0$.

Comment: It can only mean "the positive integers" since $0$ is explicitely ruled out removing any ambiguity. Whether other notations would fit better, is another story.

Comment: I can't focus enough right now to read the linked paper, but I do want to point out that this notation more often in my experience means something else than what most people here are using.  If we were talking the set of nonzero natural numbers, I more often see that as a subscript, $\Bbb N_{>0}$.  If it were an integer as a super script, such as $\Bbb N^3$ that would have been to me the set of tuples of that length (*I.e. $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ in this case*).

Comment: As such, if without context I see the notation $\Bbb N^{>0}$, my first inclination would be to read it as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb N^n$ be the set of all sequences of elements of $\Bbb N$ of any finite length.  Of course, the context of the paper will hopefully clarify which is intended, but the difference in usage of superscript and subscript is often relevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz, you are right about $\mathbb N^3$, but "$>0$" is not a set. Just read the bottom of the page 3 (starting from Putnam's argument). I think it provides enough evidence that the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is intended.